# Question about Ramanujan's congruence with modulo $5$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

There is a presentation by Michael D. Hirschhorn from University of Shanghai, you can find by searching "Simple proofs of Ramanujan's partition congruences."

It states:
$$\sum_{n\geq0} p(n)q^n = \frac{1}{E}=\frac{E^4}{E^5}=\frac{EJ}{E(q^5)}=\frac{(E_0+E_1+E_2)(J_0+J_1)}{E(q^5)} =\frac{E_0J_0+E_0J_1+E_1J_0+E_1J_1+E_2J_0+E_2J_1}{E(q^5)},\tag{1}$$
where
\begin{gather*}
E=(1-q)(1-q^2)(1-q^3)\cdots=1-q-q^2+q^5+q^7-q^{12}-q^{15}+\cdots\tag{2}\\
J=E^3 \tag{3}\\
(1-q)^5\equiv 1-q^5 \pmod{5} \tag{4}
\end{gather*}
and $E_i, J_i$ consist of exponents with $I$ modulo $5$. It further says

> ...if we look for terms in which the exponent is congruent
>   to $4$ modulo $5$, we find
>   $$\sum_{n\geq0} p(5n+4)q^{5n+4} \equiv 0  \pmod{5} \tag{5}$$

**My question is: How did they deduce (5) out of last row of (1)?**

P.S.

I am only collecting Ramanujan's work for my high school so I do not really need to understand this, but everything else is clear to me except this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the notation means. If
$$A=A(q)=a_0+a_1q+a_2q^2+\cdots$$
then $A_j$ consists of the terms of $A$ where the exponents are
congruent to $j$ modulo $5$. Therefore
$$A_3=a_3q^3+a_8q^8+a_{13}q^{13}+\cdots$$
etc.

You are confusing equalities and congruences here. First of all
$$J(q)=E(q)^3=\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m (2m+1)q^{m(m+1)/2}.$$
The exponents are triangular numbers, and these are congruent to
$0$, $1$, $3$ modulo $5$, so that
$$J=J_0+J_1+J_5.$$
However, if $5\mid m (m+1)/2$ then $5\mid (2m+1)$ so that
the coefficients of $J_3$ are all multiples of $5$. So we can write
$$J\equiv J_0+J_1\pmod 5$$
interpreted as the difference of the two sides has coefficient
divisible by $5$.

Euler's formula for $E(q)$ implies that $E=E_0+E_1+E_2$.
Therefore
$$E^4=EJ\equiv(E_0+E_1+E_2)(J_0+J_1)\pmod 5$$
and the RHS of this is a power series with zero coefficients
for the $q^m$ with $m\equiv4\pmod5$. Therefore the coefficient
for such $q^m$ in $E_4$ are divisible by $5$, equivalently $(E^4)_4
\equiv0\pmod p$.

We have $P(q)=\sum p(n)q^n=1/E=E^4/E^5$. Then $E(q)^5\equiv E(q^5)\pmod 5$
(true for any power series), so $1/E^5\equiv (1/E^5)_0\pmod 5$.
Then
$$P\equiv((E^4)_0+(E^4)_1+(E^4)_2+(E^4)_3)(1/E^5)_0\pmod 5$$
giving
$$P_4\equiv0\pmod 5.$$